# How to apply formula before the SUM()?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to do `sum()` operation. For example `sum(A1:A100)` BUT I want to apply other `function()` for every cell before the `sum()` operation. How to do this without extra additional cells.

For example the function to check if the value is bigger than 1 then it will convert it to 1. Or convert whatever number in the cell into 1.

something like:

```
= A1/A1 + A2/A2 + A3/A3 ... A100/A100
```

but I want to do it inside `sum()`. is it possible?

Comment: if it's just about converting any number to 1 before summing it up, I think you could easily replace your `sum()` function with a `count()` function. Alternatively, something with `sumproduct()` might do the trick too. As @player0 said, it's not quite clear what you're trying to do, we could use more details here.

Comment: @BenoîtWéry Thanks a lot, that count() works as i expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(A:A))))
```

[image: 0]

---

or maybe:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, A:A*1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That arrayformula() works perfectly, but the problem is i need to put this script on the same column which is column A (on top most row or 1st row) so the sum will start from the 2nd row to let say 100th row. Any solution ?

Comment: sure, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(A2:A100))))`